# Вывод информации только на первой странице пагинации

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, может кто-то подсказать как в WordPress сделать так, чтобы только на первой странице отображался текст, у меня это описание категории, а на остальных он пропадал. Искал в интернете не нашёл решения. Хотя бы ссылку почитать дайте, может плохо искал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте эти варианты:

```
if (1 < get_query_var('paged')) {
   //show content
}
```

Или такой, с использованием глобальной переменной:

```
if ($page > 1) {
   //show content
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помог первый вариант) Второй не пробовал.